# Do I need to Create A Deconstructor in C# When The Class Uses Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity

May be a dumb question, but is it prudent to create a deconstructor class on a called class that is using Entity Framework under asp.net framework 4.x? Does it provide faster release of memory elements in the class concerning entity?

I know that it's recommended to create a dispose method when calling entity directly in the mvc controller class.

Here's a sample of what I mean...

```
    public class DepartmentServices
    {
        private MyDB _db = new MyDB();

        //Deconstructor class
        ~DepartmentServices()
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the finalizer method. Your class should implement IDisposable instead. Take a look at the IDisposable pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: Thank you Jorn for your response. I see that I can inherit from the IDisposable interface class and build the disposal of the entity objects.